# After updating Mac 10.11.6, /cores is filling with core dumps

Tags: macos, mac

Can any one suggest to me how to delete the /cores directory, which is filled up with lot of core dumps automatically and my profile crashes. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

In Terminal, execute the following command: `rm -f /cores/core.*`

If you get a permissions error try: `sudo rm -f /cores/core.*` and type in your password.

Comment: done already after which machine gets dumped again and the same profile gets flickered if we login

Comment: This link provides some additional information about how to turn off core dumps, or how to automate the process of deleting core dumps on a regular schedule: [Remove hidden core dump files to restore drive space](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20031001203255412).

Comment: tried those already but no luck on it